# Is there a way to stop the 'sa' user changing records inside particular table or particular db in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, system-administration, sa

Is there a way to stop the 'sa' user changing records inside particular table or particular db in mssql? My preliminary searches did not find me anything except cell level encryption. Is there any other way?

### UPDATE

Requirement is to prevent IT users changing (inserting) records to gain access to system. other users can be prevented by restricting permission. but 'sa' user cannot. replacing sa with another account won't work as the person who has the other account would have potential to do the change and gain access.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice guideline on 'sa' account by Microsoft:

[Resource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905197%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Also you can replace 'sa' with some other account with elevated premission

[Replacing the SQL Server Default SA Account](http://www.blackthornesw.com/robo/projects/blackthornepro/HOWTO_-_Replacing_the_SQL_Server_Default_SA_Account.htm)

Comment: Requirement is to prevent IT users changing (inserting) records to gain access to system. other users can be prevented by restricting permission. but 'sa' user cannot. replacing sa with another account won't work as the person who has the other account would have potential to do the change and gain access.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: This is always the problem. Someone will always have the keys to the castle. But, at the end of the day, if you can't trust the key holders, you have larger issues.